# Handle TokenMismatchException in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, exception, laravel-5

I need to handle `TokenMismatchException` in laravel 5 such a way that if token does not match it will show some message to user instead of `TokenMismatchException` error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can create a custom [exception render](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#render-method) in the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class (in the `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file).

For example, to render a different view when for the `TokenMismatchException` error, you can change the `render` method to something like this:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
        return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 500);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: Hi Hiew. Just tried you method and unfortunately I still get a "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53" whenever I post a fake a csrf token/

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($e); die();` before the `if` statement to check whether the `rendered` method is called or not.

Comment: Yes, now I get the dirty page dump of object(Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException)#274 ...

Comment: Now I just fixed it by adding the namespace on that App\ExceptionsHandler.php class - `use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;` Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed my mistake was doing `if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException){` instead of the full path to the exception class.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You will need to write a function to render the TokenMismatchException error. You will add that function to your App\Exceptions\Handler class (in the /app/Exceptions/Handler.php file) this way:

```
// make sure you reference the full path of the class:
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {

    protected $dontReport = [
        HttpException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
        // opt from logging this error to your log files (optional)
        TokenMismatchException::class,
    ];

    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        // Handle the exception...
        // redirect back with form input except the _token (forcing a new token to be generated)
        if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException){
            return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->except('_token'))
            ->withFlashDanger('You page session expired. Please try again');
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working except that the instance must have full path:  
`if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException){`

Comment: Notice that i reference the full path of the class at the top

Comment: Can we extend this behavior by resubmit the form with data after token refreshed?