# VueJS + Laravel Passport CSRF Token Expired How to refresh it

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a page leave it for 2 hours. If I using Laravel only, when I submit the form. It will have CSRF Token expired error.

Now I have a form using VueJS. When I submitted form. In console log it showed `{message: "Unauthenticated."}`

But It actually not a unauthenticated, because after I refresh the page, it did not redirect to login page. And during my login I already tick "remember me", so the user is authenticated. I open a new page with the same URL. It is able to access. As I check the differential is the X-CSRF-TOKEN.

Below is the curl I copy from Chrome dev tool.

```
//Token Expired
curl 'https://project-a.test/api/add-stock' -H 'origin: https://project-a.test' -H 'x-xsrf-token: eyJpdiI6InVwUWpQUnAwN2w2OFU4eGhsUk11aHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOExWWk9NdWpDVSs1aFdNSVA5cDh4a1E2NFNoVlF0anZQSFV3UzI1Q1E4T045b0FGc25OQmRjN1YzS2FGK2hvayIsIm1hYyI6IjZlNjNkYTc5YTBkMmYwMzNhOThlZjRkMWI1NTJiMDA0YTI5NDFmNmQ1NWVmMDFhNjM0OTdjODYzNjk0OWZmYzcifQ==' -H 'x-csrf-token: 0vEwLewA4rDtiftLpoYgqeNkIrs6Eyb9gvRiP2Ug' -H 'accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.7,zh;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.5,id;q=0.4,ms;q=0.3,ja;q=0.2' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'cookie: remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d=eyJpdiI6ImRWSVVuNlZNcERvNXRKMkd6N2hHYmc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibHZyNHhReUp1RlNoamZJODZKWlhVQmpsSXNFOTZCeW40M2VWTEJnZzhJKzRYY2VnNjFIanFQRUZkbzh3RlFnQmhVZFF2RmhtS013bjhsc0ZWSVJUcHZmMVVDVUtQOGVDS0lNSXVcLzB5aFJNekJmRlVRUkVZeTJGTTdwTnJ1U0JQRXdac1NjWVNqdWs4XC9JSjZ1dGhTVUhQa29hcWQrUVk5REgrNGdJVTZcL1BVPSIsIm1hYyI6IjkxOTA5MmEwNmY3MmY0MGQ1OTg5YzVlNzJlZGJmMWMzODAyNjhkMzQzMDgwNTgyZGEzYjI4ZWRiYzUyN2I3ODkifQ%3D%3D; laravel_token=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%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InVwUWpQUnAwN2w2OFU4eGhsUk11aHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOExWWk9NdWpDVSs1aFdNSVA5cDh4a1E2NFNoVlF0anZQSFV3UzI1Q1E4T045b0FGc25OQmRjN1YzS2FGK2hvayIsIm1hYyI6IjZlNjNkYTc5YTBkMmYwMzNhOThlZjRkMWI1NTJiMDA0YTI5NDFmNmQ1NWVmMDFhNjM0OTdjODYzNjk0OWZmYzcifQ%3D%3D; longvision_malaysia_stock_management_session=eyJpdiI6IkV3TjJGOFhzdkdKTEpCKzJuVjZUYkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidTNFXC9rbUg3S2JubXErZm1VN3JEOGhXbEx6QXBCYVpWTldvcHQ0UDM2WEhCTHBWNVwvV1FwSDVKYTlwdDMzTG5hIiwibWFjIjoiY2M0ZGRlZjUzYWIwMWE2M2U2YjVjYjUwMGNhMzNmNGVjZDcxMzcwZDczZDY3Njc0OWM5NzI2YTY1MjE2ZTEwOCJ9' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'referer: https://lvm-stock.test/request-assets-add' -H 'authority: lvm-stock.test' --data-binary '{"qty":{"1":0,"2":0},"remark":"","customer":""}' --compressed

//After refresh the page, it updated the CSRF Token value which is working
curl 'https://project-a.test/api/add-stock' -H 'origin: https://project-a.test' -H 'x-xsrf-token: eyJpdiI6InVwUWpQUnAwN2w2OFU4eGhsUk11aHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOExWWk9NdWpDVSs1aFdNSVA5cDh4a1E2NFNoVlF0anZQSFV3UzI1Q1E4T045b0FGc25OQmRjN1YzS2FGK2hvayIsIm1hYyI6IjZlNjNkYTc5YTBkMmYwMzNhOThlZjRkMWI1NTJiMDA0YTI5NDFmNmQ1NWVmMDFhNjM0OTdjODYzNjk0OWZmYzcifQ==' -H 'x-csrf-token: kmp9fz2SGMXx0gEYuUymH5eNitgCs6IoDwNE68kX' -H 'accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.7,zh;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.5,id;q=0.4,ms;q=0.3,ja;q=0.2' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'cookie: remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d=eyJpdiI6ImRWSVVuNlZNcERvNXRKMkd6N2hHYmc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibHZyNHhReUp1RlNoamZJODZKWlhVQmpsSXNFOTZCeW40M2VWTEJnZzhJKzRYY2VnNjFIanFQRUZkbzh3RlFnQmhVZFF2RmhtS013bjhsc0ZWSVJUcHZmMVVDVUtQOGVDS0lNSXVcLzB5aFJNekJmRlVRUkVZeTJGTTdwTnJ1U0JQRXdac1NjWVNqdWs4XC9JSjZ1dGhTVUhQa29hcWQrUVk5REgrNGdJVTZcL1BVPSIsIm1hYyI6IjkxOTA5MmEwNmY3MmY0MGQ1OTg5YzVlNzJlZGJmMWMzODAyNjhkMzQzMDgwNTgyZGEzYjI4ZWRiYzUyN2I3ODkifQ%3D%3D; laravel_token=eyJpdiI6Iml6YUxjOUxBWHFOOXozazFrUnkxXC9BPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Ikt1emoxTHJcL05obzVrOXFManJcL3ViSzV4M1Z4TjhGcjlJNHdzNTVteEVFUG5XN0JDcEVqaWVsXC9CNnNxTjl5UStMNG9QRUdQZjNcL1dEQTJGOVZ6cDZ2Nk1TMGZNTzBBS01tQiswZjgwV3lIaVpXR25BTm13MDhNeWV2S3cyNU0xYmNxNGxcL0JVQ3BKclF5eUNMMmc3TnF5THR4MFl6VnRCS3lJR0RCSWhBb3YwZHBMUGFqZ25NcEtiT0RnenJsRmFnZjgwSDJCTHhISEVueW51amNDVXpcL0JYdzY2blAwYTFBTXpnb05EMElEdGJrOTQ2a2pNNVhMVWJtUU55OWxrczYiLCJtYWMiOiJkM2Q0NTU3ZDVjZDY0NWM0MDM2MjQ3Njk4N2Y3NzY0OThlMTJiYjllMWFlMjNjN2JmMWUxN2E3ZTFmYmJkM2Y2In0%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InVwUWpQUnAwN2w2OFU4eGhsUk11aHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOExWWk9NdWpDVSs1aFdNSVA5cDh4a1E2NFNoVlF0anZQSFV3UzI1Q1E4T045b0FGc25OQmRjN1YzS2FGK2hvayIsIm1hYyI6IjZlNjNkYTc5YTBkMmYwMzNhOThlZjRkMWI1NTJiMDA0YTI5NDFmNmQ1NWVmMDFhNjM0OTdjODYzNjk0OWZmYzcifQ%3D%3D; longvision_malaysia_stock_management_session=eyJpdiI6IkV3TjJGOFhzdkdKTEpCKzJuVjZUYkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidTNFXC9rbUg3S2JubXErZm1VN3JEOGhXbEx6QXBCYVpWTldvcHQ0UDM2WEhCTHBWNVwvV1FwSDVKYTlwdDMzTG5hIiwibWFjIjoiY2M0ZGRlZjUzYWIwMWE2M2U2YjVjYjUwMGNhMzNmNGVjZDcxMzcwZDczZDY3Njc0OWM5NzI2YTY1MjE2ZTEwOCJ9' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'referer: https://project-a.test/request-assets-add' -H 'authority: project-a.test' --data-binary '{"qty":{"1":0,"2":0},"remark":"","customer":""}' --compressed
```

I think generally Laravel will just return general message 'Unauthenticated.'. How to I notify user it is not Unauthenticated error, but they just need to refresh the page. Or it is able to prompt a message?

I tried in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` added following line:-

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
            return response()->view('index', ['message' => 'custom message'], 500);
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

But it is still return Unauthenticated error.

```
Laravel Framework: v5.7.24
Laravel Passport: v7.1.0
VueJS: v2.5.21
```

Comment: which HTTP client you're using? axious or jquery ...?

Comment: I am using HTTP client Axious

Comment: did it get resolve? I am facing same error with same version of laravel and passport.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should customize the token mismatch error message, then show it to your user.
please check the following post to customized the error response.

[How to handle Token Mismatch Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310021/how-to-handel-token-mismatch-exception)

Comment: It's work for normal Laravel, but not with API base. This was I tried with fully Laravel app. But this one I work with API, I updated my questions.

Comment: hmm.. you are trying to return a view but this is not the case, you must try JSON response and show that response to the user like `return response()->json(['message' => 'custom message'], 500);` now show the response message to the user.