# Handle TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php, refreshing the page in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Laravel 5.3

I wish handle TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php.
Normally this exception occurs when I haven't refresh current page, and the previous token persist, so I reload the page, new token is set and I can do login process.
Ok, but, I wish handle the exception and refresh automatically the page.

Is this possible?

Comment: This question was resolved like a year before. Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846788/handle-tokenmismatchexception-in-laravel-5

Comment: I have to try to search better. Thanks Julian

Comment: try https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine for prevent expire form tokens

Comment: as @kscorrales mentioned - try laravel-caffeine it's working pretty good

Comment: Thanks for this tip kscorrales! I try it this morning!

Answer (score 3):

If you still wish to handle Handle TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php
Here is the way forward in laravel 5.3.
find the **VerifyCsrfToken.php** In a middleware directory

> app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php

make sure you add,

> use Closure;

to avoid Declaration exception error.
Then add the handle method to compare sessionToken and form input Token.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if($request->input('_token'))
  {
    if ( \Session::getToken() != $request->input('_token'))
    {

      notify()->flash('Your session has expired. Please try logging in again.', 'warning');

      return redirect()->guest('/login');
    }
  }
  return parent::handle($request, $next);
}
```

A vivid insight: Totally optional

- Checking If Session token matches request token(The token in the input hidden)

> dd(\Session::getToken() == $request->input('_token'));

- Log an error that the session has expired its totally optional

> \Log::error("Expired token found. Redirecting to /");

- flash the error message with redirect response to the login page

> return redirect()->guest('/')
>           ->with('global', 'Expired token found. Redirecting to /');

- note:

  If this if statement is not true , the return value(return parent::handle($request, $next);) will be excuted
  that means if there is the a problem with a token, An **Error Exception** will be thrown (**TokenMismatch** exception). This may be because by forgetting adding the **{{ csrf_field() }}** in the form so as the result the **$request->input('_token')** can not be found or its empty.
- Notice:

  Am using codecourse/notify (https://github.com/codecourse/notify)
  to flash message thats why i used,

> notify()->flash('Your session has expired. Please try logging in
>   again.', 'warning');

its totally optional if you want to flash message without the package.
You can use laravel implimentation. So it will be something like

> return redirect()->guest('/')
>     ->with('global', 'Expired token found. Redirecting to /');