# Laravel: How to prevent TokenMismatchException when idle?

Tags: laravel, csrf

I have been suffering this TokenMismatchException. So I was figuring what causes the error. I found out that If I try to idle the landing page for 15minutes then login. I got the TokenMismatchException. I have a {!! csrf_field() !!} in the loginform.

My config/session.php lifetime is set to 15 minutes. So I've waited 15minutes to catch the TokenMismatchException error.

So I have tried these several solutions

1. installed laravel-caffeine
2. `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`
3. Edited the Handler.php

   `public function render($request, Exception $e)
   {
     if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
          return redirect('/login')->with('message', 'Security token expired. Please, login back.');
      }
      if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
      return redirect('/login')->with('message', 'Security token expired. Please, login back.');
     }
       return parent::render($request, $e);
   }`

But nothing seems working.

Comment: You don't need laravel-caffeine for this. Mostly likely your exception catcher is correct, just either namespaces are wrong or it's in the wrong place

Comment: @Kenyon , check my code, I tried using 2 exceptions. Still not working.

Comment: I copied the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31846916/7146565

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. You could edit `App\Exceptions\Handler` like this

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

    if($this->isTokenMismatchException($e)) {

        if(!(Auth::check()))  return $this->redirectGuestToLogin();

    } 

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}

protected function redirectGuestToLogin(){

    return redirect()->guest('auth/login');

}

protected function isTokenMismatchException(Exception $e){

      return $e instanceof TokenMismatchException;

}
```

Comment: Do you know if the handler is called and if it detect the TokenMismatchException?

Comment: I really don't know.

Comment: Add `Log::info("Some text")` in each if block to see if they work. You can then look in your logs what code was executed

Comment: Wait, I need to check if I am using the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

My code in Handler was right. But my mistake is that I was using the older version of the project in the browser. That is why I am still getting the error. Now it's totally working.

Comment: I didn't understand the error about `using the older version of the project in the browser`. Could you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: the actual project is supposed to be "http://localhost/myrcf-version-3" and I was running the "http://localhost/myrcf/" the whole time.